# GCM opening notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing the GCM with the following code:
This is for GMCIntentService.java

```
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

          displayMessage(context, message);

        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        //notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        //notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        //notificationIntent.setAction(message);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP ); 
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

And the following code is for MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;
// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;

public static String name;
public static String email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //setContentView(lblMessage);
    //setContentView(R.string.gcm_message);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting name, email from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");      

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
    //prova.append(lblMessage.getText().toString());

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter( 
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    //lblMessage.append(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //lblMessage.getText().toString();


    //lblMessage.append(getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
    //lblMessage.getText().toString();

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext())) {

            // Skips registration
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}       

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */
        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

the system works fine, but when I receive a notification, it is shown in the notification bar, but clicking on the notification opens a blank page where only view the messages later, at app open while the one sent before it was written in the notification I can view it. This is not a large operation, because it received notification I also want to see it completely.

Comment: I had this same issue... if the issue is still unresolved, please replace the code for PendingIntent with the below code.

PendingIntent intent =                 PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); and if you solved the issue, could you please let me know if you have tested the app in new Android kitkat cause I am facing the issue for kitkat only. Other version does work well with the above code.